# Is an EC2 nano instance powerful enough to be used as a proxyserver that uses openVPN?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to create my own VPN for personal use. I want to use EC2 nano instances for that because those instances are the cheapest.

My question is: Is a nano instance powerful enough to be used as a proxyserver that uses openVPN?

EDIT: Just to clarify a bit more; The VPN will be used by me only. So the proxy server will never have to handle more than one connection at a time. So there won't be much load on the EC2 nano instance.

Comment: Is my car large enough for my groceries? Sizing depends on the load.

Comment: @vidarlo i've added an extra detail, please read my edit. thanks

Comment: You haven't really clarified it. Best suggestion would be to test it The cost is minimal, and if doesn't offer enough performance, swap out for a larger instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

It might be, as @vidarlo says, easiest way to find out is to test it. AWS has a free usage tier so it shouldn't cost anything (certainly not more than a few dollars).

Another option is to set up something like [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) at home on a raspberry pi, and leave it running. I did exactly this on a Pi Zero-W and it was sufficient to stream HD video whilst abroad. Other than the electricity cost, the only cost was buying the Pi, but that was cheaper than running an EC2 instance 24 hours a day.

Update: You could also plug in some data to [the calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) and see how much it would cost you depending on EC2 specs/data transfer/storage etc.

Comment: EC2 instances can be put into hibernate mode when you don't use them.

Comment: Yes, you can turn them off, but then any time you want to use your VPN you have to turn it back on. That's not necessarily a problem, but something to bear in mind.

Comment: Plus you'll still pay for the EBS storage used by the machine, and network traffic exiting AWS. So factor that in too!